# Angular dynamic component can't use component from different module

Tags: angular

This is the scenario (check this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jfun8y?file=src/app/app.component.ts)):

- I have two modules: `AppModule` and `OtherModule`.
- In `AppComponent` (from AppModule), I create two dynamic components, using
  `FirstComponent` and `SecondComponent`.
- In the `FirstComponent` template I insert `HelloComponent`, that belongs to the same module (AppModule), and it works fine.
- The problem comes in the `SecondComponent`, where I insert `ThirdComponent`, that belongs to `OtherModule`. I receive the error: **'third' is not a known element**.
- `OtherModule` is imported in `AppModule`.
- If I remove `<third></third>` from `second.component.html` the app will run, but I need to insert `ThirdComponent` inside `SecondComponent`, and SecondComponent is dynamic.

So, how can I use inside a dynamic component a component from a different module?

Angular CLI: 12.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export the components that throw errors. What I mean is that you need to include the third component in the exports array in OtherModule. It should work.